Empty stringConnection in DbContext and Set after in middleware
I'm developing an application, for security policy, the connection string can only be obtained in the API consumption, additionally, this is provided by the class library. I was allowed to modify it to create a version of the builder for EF.
I'm trying this:
This is code from class library:
public DbManagerEF(string connectionString)
{            
    dataConnection = connectionProvider.GetConnectionProvider(connectionString);                        
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
        
    string stringConexion = "Server=" + dataConnection.serverName + ";Database=" + dataConnection.dataBaseDefault + ";User ID=" + dataConnection.userName + ";Password=" + dataConnection.userPasword;

    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(stringConexion);
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);  
 }


My DbContext it has two constructors:

public DbManagerEF(string connectionString)
{            
     dataConnection = connectionProvider.GetConnectionProvider(connectionString);                        
}


protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
            
    string stringConexion = "Server=" + dataConnection.serverName + ";Database=" + dataConnection.dataBaseDefault + ";User ID=" + dataConnection.userName + ";Password=" + dataConnection.userPasword;
    
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(stringConexion);
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);  
}

This is connection provider code :

    public interface IConnectionsProvider
    {        
        string GetConnection();
        void SetConnection(string tagConnection);
        string tagConnection { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class ConnectionsProvider: IConnectionsProvider
    {
        public string tagConnection;
    
        string IConnectionsProvider.tagConnection
        {
            get { return tagConnection; }
            set { tagConnection = value; }
        }
    
        public ConnectionsProvider(){            
        }
        
        public ConnectionsProvider(string tagConnection){
    
            tagConnection = tagConnection;
        }
    
        public string GetConnection(){
            return tagConnection;
        }
    
        public void SetConnection(string tagConnection)
        {
            tagConnection = tagConnection;
        }
    }


My middleware:
    public class ConnectionMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly IConnectionsProvider _connectionsProvider;
    
        public ConnectionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IConnectionsProvider connectionsProvider)
        {
            _next = next;
            _connectionsProvider = connectionsProvider;
        }
    
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, Func<HospitalContext> contextFactory)
        {            
            var connectionString = context.Request.Headers["Conexion"];            
            _connectionsProvider.SetConnection(connectionString);
    
            var dbContext = new HospitalContext(_connectionsProvider.GetConnection());
            await _next(context);
        }      
    }

My StartUp :
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddScoped<HospitalContext>();
            services.AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication")
                    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", null);

            services.AddSingleton<Func<HospitalContext>>(provider =>
            {
                var dbContext = provider.GetRequiredService<HospitalContext>();
                return () => dbContext;
            });
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();

            services.AddSingleton<IConnectionsProvider>(provider =>
            {                                
                return new ConnectionsProvider();
            });
        }

And is in this point where I get the connection string:
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ConnectionMiddleware>();
}

My problem is this.
When the connectionScript is configured in the ConnectionMiddleware, the context is correct, but when the controller is called the values from HospitalContext is lost.
How can I maintain the values ​​of the HospitalContext created in the middleware when the controller is called?  It is possible to achieve this with a service that returns an instance of DBContext.
This is the code from my controller:
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConnectionsProvider _connectionsProvider;
        private readonly HospitalContext _hospitalContext;

        public HospitalController(IConnectionsProvider connectionsProvider, HospitalContext dbContext)
        {
            _connectionsProvider = connectionsProvider;
            _hospitalContext     = dbContext;
        }
 }


Hi @Emerson Rios, pls share enough code about IConnectionsProvider . And try to register HospitalContext with a scoped lifetime:services.AddScoped<HospitalContext>();. Also remember to inject HospitalContext into your middleware.

thanks @Rena, I update my post with the IConnectionsProvider code, this object only retrieves information with which the connection string is constructed. I also did the test by registering HospitalContext with scoped duration and got the same result.
